# Do cameras have to be calibrated in order to be used with StereoBM?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereoscopy

In my situation, the data returned by the OpenCV StereoBM Depth Map does not make sense Regardless of Parameter Tuning.

I'm doing research for a design project that involves OpenCV and using stereo vision to generate a depth map. I'm currently successfully able to load both my web cameras and generate a depth map using the StereoBM. However, the result data isn't useful at the moment as my screenshot demonstrates below. So I created a small python app that helps me tune the StereoBM parameters which hasn't helped.

My question do the cameras have to be calibrated in order to be used with the StereoBM function?

If not, what are some alternatives to help me improve my results (i.e. increase resolution, use StereoSBGM, etc.)

[image]

**Code**

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
from Tkinter import *

oldVal = 15
def oddVals(n):
        global oldVal
        n = int(n)
        if not n % 2:
                window_size.set(n+1 if n > oldVal else n-1)
                oldVal = window_size.get()

minDispValues = [16,32,48,64]
def minDispCallback(n):
        n = int(n)
        newvalue = min(minDispValues, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(n)))
        min_disp.set(newvalue)

# Display the sliders to control the stereo vision 
master = Tk()

master.title("StereoBM Settings");

min_disp = Scale(master, from_=16, to=64, command=minDispCallback, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Minimum Disparities")
min_disp.pack()
min_disp.set(16)

window_size = Scale(master, from_=5, to=255, command=oddVals, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Window Size")
window_size.pack()
window_size.set(15)

Disp12MaxDiff = Scale(master, from_=5, to=30, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Max Difference")
Disp12MaxDiff.pack()
Disp12MaxDiff.set(0)

UniquenessRatio = Scale(master, from_=0, to=30, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Uniqueness Ratio")
UniquenessRatio.pack()
UniquenessRatio.set(15)

SpeckleRange = Scale(master, from_=0, to=60, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Speckle Range")
SpeckleRange.pack()
SpeckleRange.set(34)

SpeckleWindowSize = Scale(master, from_=60, to=150, length=600, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Speckle Window Size")
SpeckleWindowSize.pack()
SpeckleWindowSize.set(100)

master.update()

vcLeft = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Load video campture for the left camera
#vcLeft.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,420);
#vcLeft.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,340);
vcLeft.set(3,640) # Set camera width
vcLeft.set(4,480) # Set camera height

vcRight = cv2.VideoCapture(1) # Load video capture for the right camera
#vcRight.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,420);
#vcRight.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,340);

firstTime = time.time() # First time log

totalFramesPassed = 0 # Number of frames passed

if vcLeft.isOpened() and vcRight.isOpened():
        rvalLeft, frameLeft = vcLeft.read()
        rvalRight, frameRight = vcRight.read()

else:
        rvalLeft = False
        rvalRight = False

while rvalLeft and rvalRight: # If the cameras are opened

        rvalLeft, frameLeft = vcLeft.read()

        rvalRight, frameRight = vcRight.read()

        cv2.putText(frameLeft, "FPS : " + str(totalFramesPassed / (time.time() - firstTime)),(40, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, 150, 2, 10)

        cv2.imshow("Left Camera", frameLeft)

        cv2.putText(frameRight, "FPS : " + str(totalFramesPassed / (time.time() - firstTime)),(40, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, 150, 2, 10)

        cv2.imshow("Right Camera", frameRight)

        frameLeftNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameLeft, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        frameRightNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameRight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        num_disp = 112 - min_disp.get()

        stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = num_disp, blockSize = window_size.get())

        stereo.setMinDisparity(min_disp.get())

        stereo.setNumDisparities(num_disp)

        stereo.setBlockSize(window_size.get())

        stereo.setDisp12MaxDiff(Disp12MaxDiff.get())

        stereo.setUniquenessRatio(UniquenessRatio.get())

        stereo.setSpeckleRange(SpeckleRange.get())

        stereo.setSpeckleWindowSize(SpeckleWindowSize.get())

        disparity = stereo.compute(frameLeftNew, frameRightNew).astype(np.float32) / 16.0

        disp_map = (disparity - min_disp.get())/num_disp

        cv2.imshow("Disparity", disp_map)

        master.update() # Update the slider options

        key = cv2.waitKey(20)

        totalFramesPassed = totalFramesPassed + 1 # One frame passed, increment

        if key == 27:

                break


vcLeft.release()

vcRight.release()
```

Comment: Having cameras calibrated - especially undistorted will help. Have you tried to use StereoBM with more random scenes (text, random dots, etc?) - maybe it is a problem with correspondences. I would try to implement simple correlation algorithm and see how good corelation is.

Comment: @KamilSzelag Thanks for the advice. I will defiantly try to calibrate both images the left and right images so that hopefully the algorithm can work better. I've tried to use StereoBM with other scenes but I will check if correlation is good in my scenes. I hope calibration is the main issue here as my current results, even with a lot of objects in the scene, are unreliable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the opencv documentation of StereoBM [opencv stereoBM doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20StereoBM::operator()(InputArray%20left,%20InputArray%20right,%20OutputArray%20disparity,%20int%20disptype)) the two images needs to be a "rectified stereo pair".

This means that before you compute the disparity you will need to rectify the two cameras.

Have a look at [stereo_match](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp) where you can see how to rectify the two cameras before you compute the disparity.

When you are computing the disparity using the stereoBM you are looking at the correspondence of the parallel epipolar lines in both images.
This means that the images are expected to be aligned in such a away that the same rows in both images correspond to the same lines in space. The rectification process takes care of that.

For more information look at [Rectification with opencv](http://ece631web.groups.et.byu.net/Lectures/ECEn631%2014%20-%20Calibration%20and%20Rectification.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we need to rectify the pair in order to use the StereoBM function. Furthermore, I found out that although it is more resource intensive, the StereoSGBM function gave me more optimal results.

In case anyone needs to calibrate their cameras in the future, you can use this code to help you do so:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Constants
leftCameraNumber = 2 # Number for left camera
rightCameraNumber = 1 # Number for right camera

numberOfChessRows = 6
numberOfChessColumns = 8
chessSquareSize = 30 # Length of square in millimeters

numberOfChessColumns = numberOfChessColumns - 1 # Update to reflect how many corners are inside the chess board
numberOfChessRows = numberOfChessRows - 1

objp = np.zeros((numberOfChessColumns*numberOfChessRows,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:numberOfChessRows,0:numberOfChessColumns].T.reshape(-1,2)*chessSquareSize

objectPoints = []
leftImagePoints = []
rightImagePoints = []

parameterCriteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# Code
print("Press \"n\" when you're done caputing checkerboards.")

vcLeft = cv2.VideoCapture(leftCameraNumber) # Load video campture for the left camera
vcLeft.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640*3/2);
vcLeft.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480*3/2);

vcRight = cv2.VideoCapture(rightCameraNumber) # Load video capture for the right camera
vcRight.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640*3/2);
vcRight.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480*3/2);

if vcLeft.isOpened() and vcRight.isOpened():
    rvalLeft, frameLeft = vcLeft.read()
    rvalRight, frameRight = vcRight.read()

else:
    rvalLeft = False
    rvalRight = False

# Number of succesful recognitions
checkerboardRecognitions = 0

while rvalLeft and rvalRight: # If the cameras are opened

    vcLeft.grab();

    vcRight.grab();

    rvalLeft, frameLeft = vcLeft.retrieve()

    rvalRight, frameRight = vcRight.retrieve()

    frameLeftNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameLeft, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    frameRightNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameRight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    foundPatternLeft, cornersLeft = cv2.findChessboardCorners(frameLeftNew, (numberOfChessRows, numberOfChessColumns), None, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK)

    foundPatternRight, cornersRight = cv2.findChessboardCorners(frameRightNew, (numberOfChessRows, numberOfChessColumns), None, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK)


    if foundPatternLeft and foundPatternRight: # If found corners in this frame

        # Process the images and display the count of checkboards in our array
        checkerboardRecognitions = checkerboardRecognitions + 1
        print("Checker board recognitions: " + str(checkerboardRecognitions))

        objectPoints.append(objp)

        exactCornersLeft = cv2.cornerSubPix(frameLeftNew, cornersLeft, (11, 11), (-1, -1), parameterCriteria);
        leftImagePoints.append(exactCornersLeft)

        exactCornersRight = cv2.cornerSubPix(frameRightNew, cornersRight, (11, 11), (-1, -1), parameterCriteria);
        rightImagePoints.append(exactCornersRight)

        frameLeft = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frameLeft, (numberOfChessRows, numberOfChessColumns), (exactCornersLeft), True);

        frameRight = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frameRight, (numberOfChessRows, numberOfChessColumns), (exactCornersRight), True);


    # Display current webcams regardless if board was found or not
    cv2.imshow("Left Camera", frameLeft)

    cv2.imshow("Right Camera", frameRight)


    key = cv2.waitKey(250) # Give the frame some time

    if key == ord('n'):

        break

cameraMatrixLeft = np.zeros( (3,3) )
cameraMatrixRight = np.zeros( (3,3) )
distortionLeft = np.zeros( (8,1) )
distortionRight = np.zeros( (8,1) )
height, width = frameLeft.shape[:2]

rms, leftMatrix, leftDistortion, rightMatrix, rightDistortion, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, leftImagePoints, rightImagePoints,  cameraMatrixLeft, distortionLeft, cameraMatrixRight, distortionRight, (width, height),parameterCriteria, flags=0)

arr1 = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
arr2 = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
np.savez('camera_calibration.npz', leftMatrix=leftMatrix, leftDistortion=leftDistortion, rightMatrix=rightMatrix, rightDistortion=rightDistortion, R=R, T=T, E=E, F=F)
print("Calibration Settings Saved to File!")

print("RMS:")
print(rms)
print("Left Matrix:")
print(leftMatrix)
print("Left Distortion:")
print(leftDistortion)
print("Right Matrix:")
print(rightMatrix)
print("Right Distortion:")
print(rightDistortion)
print("R:")
print(R)
print("T:")
print(T)
print("E:")
print(E)
print("F:")
print(F)


leftRectTransform, rightRectTransform, leftProjMatrix, rightProjMatrix, _, _, _ = cv2.stereoRectify(leftMatrix, leftDistortion, rightMatrix, rightDistortion,  (width, height), R, T, alpha=-1);
leftMapX, leftMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(leftMatrix, leftDistortion, leftRectTransform, leftProjMatrix, (width, height), cv2.CV_32FC1);
rightMapX, rightMapY = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(rightMatrix, rightDistortion, rightRectTransform, rightProjMatrix, (width, height), cv2.CV_32FC1);

minimumDisparities = 0
maximumDisparities = 128

stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minimumDisparities, maximumDisparities, 18)

while True: # If the cameras are opened
    vcLeft.grab();

    vcRight.grab();

    rvalLeft, frameLeft = vcLeft.retrieve()

    rvalRight, frameRight = vcRight.retrieve()

    frameLeftNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameLeft, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    frameRightNew = cv2.cvtColor(frameRight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    leftRectified = cv2.remap(frameLeftNew, leftMapX, leftMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR);

    rightRectified = cv2.remap(frameRightNew, rightMapX, rightMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR);

    disparity = stereo.compute(leftRectified, rightRectified)

    cv2.filterSpeckles(disparity, 0, 6000, maximumDisparities);

    cv2.imshow("Normalized Disparity", (disparity/16.0 - minimumDisparities)/maximumDisparities);

    cv2.imshow("Left Camera", leftRectified)

    cv2.imshow("Right Camera", rightRectified)


    key = cv2.waitKey(10) # Give the frame some time

    if key == 27:

        break

print("Finished!")
```